# trouble with ng-modal while calling it in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here are the steps I took:

1) I downloaded the script file from: https://github.com/doodeec/dcom-angular-dialog

2) included in my webpage and in my application:

```
var summariesApp = angular.module('summariesApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCkeditor', 'dcModal']);
```

3) Tried to use it in a controller:

```
summariesApp.controller("singleSNPController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.stopLightModal = dialogService.create('../Templates/test.html');
```

I get an error that the dialogService resource is not found. I know this question is a little simplistic but I have been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try injecting dialogService into your controller like this:

```
summariesApp.controller("singleSNPController", function ($scope, $http, dialogService) {

    $scope.stopLightModal = dialogService.create('../Templates/test.html');
```

Take a look at the example [here](https://github.com/doodeec/dcom-angular-dialog/blob/master/demo/scripts/controllers/main.js), you will see how they are injecting dialogService into the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past. It works extremely well and is very well documented:

https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog